# "Broken down by <singular vs. plural>"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

The sentence in question is,

> "Hardening timescales are plotted against separation in Fig.2, **broken down by hardening mechanism**."

It was suggested that I change this to `"hardening mechanisms"`.  I'm pretty sure this is incorrect, and the interwebs seem to agree (although this is a difficult topic to search for).  See: http://alt.usage.english.narkive.com/f3XfjY8U/in-a-breakdown-by-singular-or-plural,
http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/broken-down-by-noun-s.2749774/
http://www.indiana.edu/~wts/pamphlets/proofing_grammar.shtml  (has example using singular).

1) Is there a name / description for this type of situation / problem?  Are there other constructs it is analogous to?

2) Which is correct, singular or plural?  And **why** (i.e. what is the general rule)?

Comment: Consider this analogous phrasing: "200 years ago, a school was often a single room, where all the students attended.  Now (except, perhaps, in the tiniest or most impoverished areas) students are separated ***by age.***" (not "by ages")

Answer (score 1):

You are quoting the name of the measurement or category, 'hardening mechanism'. It doesn't need to change.

Not a grammarian's answer, but consider that if you wrote it as

> "Hardening timescales are plotted against separation in Fig.2, **each** broken down by **its** hardening mechanism."

It's clear that this should not be pluralised.